# Karaf - Error rendering Swagger API due "org.apache.camel.model.cloud" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I am trying to build camel-rest dsl with KARAF, but the swagger seemed isn't work.

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.apache.camel.model.cloud" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:260) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:48) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:302) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.xml.jaxb.DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.newJAXBContext(DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.java:39) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.xml.jaxb.DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.newJAXBContext(DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.java:29) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.xml.jaxb.JaxbModelToXMLDumper.getJAXBContext(JaxbModelToXMLDumper.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.xml.jaxb.JaxbModelToXMLDumper.dumpModelAsXml(JaxbModelToXMLDumper.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerSupport.getRestDefinitions(RestSwaggerSupport.java:152) ~[!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerSupport.renderResourceListing(RestSwaggerSupport.java:232) ~[!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerProcessor.process(RestSwaggerProcessor.java:120) [!/:3.5.0]
```

It is just a normal rest configuration

```
   restConfiguration()
                // Use the 'servlet' component.
                .component("jetty")
                .host("localhost").port(8080)
                // Allow Camel to try to marshal/unmarshal between Java objects and JSON
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .dataFormatProperty("mustBeJAXBElement", "false")
                .apiContextPath("api-doc")
                .apiProperty("api.title", "User API")
                .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
                .enableCORS(true);

   rest().path("/api")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .produces("application/json")
                .get()
                .outType(ResponseType.class)
                       .description("Get Response").type(ResponseType.class)
                       .param().name("ab").type(RestParamType.path).description("blah").endParam() 
   ...
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.karaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Calling as rest dsl service is working fine, but swagger API is not working, the `camel-core-engine` did have the jaxb.index file. I can't find any reason why felix cannot find it, or felix didn't include this file?

Comment: How do you run this in OSGi/Karaf? As if you use camel-core-osgi yourself and somehow create a camel context yourself then OSGi classloading and whatnot is a problem and you need to be correct/careful how to setup this. Otherwise you get osgi classloading _hell_ as you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will be fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16040 .  I don't think this impacts blueprint users but as Claus mentions in the comment if you create your own camel context you'll need a camel release that includes this fix.